# Labelling a stacked dataset

Tags: r, calculated-columns

For each year there are two groups, where the first group is stacked on top of the second group. I would like to add a column denoting which group a row is in: first or second. I've marked groups for this example, but the field does not appear in the real dataset.

```
year measure data ...
1991       1  ...  [group 1]
1991       2       [group 1] 
1991       3       [group 1] 
1991       1       [group 2] 
1991       2       [group 2] 
1991       3       [group 2] 
1991       4       [group 2] 
1992       1       [group 1] 
1992       2       [group 1] 
1992       3       [group 1]
1992       1       [group 2] 
1992       2       [group 2] 
1992       3       [group 2] 
1992       4       [group 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with either `data.table`, `dplyr` or `base R` methods.  Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'year', we check the difference of adjacent elements of 'measure' is less than 0, get the cumulative sum, and `paste` with 'group' to create the 'grp' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := paste("group", cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(measure) < 0))), year]
df1   
#    year measure     grp
#1: 1991       1 group 1
#2: 1991       2 group 1
#3: 1991       3 group 1
#4: 1991       1 group 2
#5: 1991       2 group 2
#6: 1991       3 group 2
#7: 1991       4 group 2
#8: 1992       1 group 1
#9: 1992       2 group 1
#10:1992       3 group 1
#11:1992       1 group 2
#12:1992       2 group 2
#13:1992       3 group 2
#14:1992       4 group 2
```

---

The same methodology can be used in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(grp = paste("group", cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(measure) < 0))))
```

Comment: What is this mechanic doing? `cumsum(c(TRUE, `

Comment: @Hatshepsut the `diff` returns a length of one less than the original length, so we concatenate with `TRUE` after converting the diff output to logical and when we do cumsum, the the TRUE/FALSE coerces to binary and for every TRUE value, one gets added.